# Issues converting MySQL datetime with PHP's date function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use PHP to convert some of my database's datetime entries so that they appear with the full month name, day, and year: ex. July 08 2011

The entries in the database all have the correct dates and times, but when I try converting them, they show up in the correct format but the day becomes the month (08 shows up as August), the day shows up as the year (11), and the month shows up as the year (July shows up as 2007). So July 08 2011 gets converted to August 11, 2007.

Code:

```
$date2 = date('F j Y', strtotime($date));
```

Anyone know what might be up?

```
var_dump($date):

string(14) "07-07-11 01:32"
```

More code:

```
            while($get_row = mysql_fetch_array($get_rs)) {
                $gb_str2 .= $tableOpen;
                $name = $get_row["Name"];
                $email = $get_row["Email"];
                $comment = $get_row["Comment"];
                $date = $get_row["Date"];


                if(!empty($name)) {
                    // If name exists and email exists, link name to email
                    if(!empty($email)) {
                        $name="by <a href=\"mailto:$email\">$name</a>";
                    }
                // If name does exist and email exists, link email to email     
                } elseif (!empty($email)) {
                    $name = "by <a href=\"mailto:$email\">$email</a>";
                // Else make name blank 
                } else {
                    $name = "";
                }

                // Append to string we'll print later on
                $date2 = date('F j Y', strtotime($date));

                $gb_str2 .= "$comment<hr>< posted on $date2 $name>".$tableClose."<br>";

            }
```

Comment: give us result of `var_dump($date);` additionally

Comment: MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format, so you're definitely manipulating it somehow

Comment: @tim: `string(14) "07-07-11 01:32"` --- are you **sure** that the underlying mysql type is `datetime`? Because it doesn't look like valid mysql datetime

Comment: positive... all the entries are in the format: 2011-07-07 01:32:22

Comment: I have no idea how it's getting 07-07-11 01:32. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason,

```
$date = date('F jS Y', strtotime($get_row['date']));
```

did the trick. I still don't really understand what was going wrong.